# Not able to click on "Confirm Email" link using selenium webdriver (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I want to click "Confirm Email Address" link from email body.But, can't locate the element  of it as it has link references.I have tried using link text & cssSelector but, it still not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Confirm Email Address")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//a[contains(text(),'Confirm')]")).click();
```

Comment: Post the html and the error message. You tried `xpath` syntax in `cssSelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a Wait problem. You need to wait for that element for its visibility. Try the code below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Confirm Email Address"))).click();
```

Comment: elementToBeClickable